# How to set disk memory allocated to a spark job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mlflow

I launched an application python from a spark submit which loads machine learning models from MLFlow using `mlflow.sklearn.load_model`.

However, I got the following error :
`mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: The following failures occurred while downloading one or more artifacts from  {model.pkl: OSError(28, No space left on device)}`

It seems that the filesystem where the application is writing the model on when calling `mlflow.sklearn.load_model` has not enough resources.

Do you have a work around to load my model ? I would add that I already minimize the model size using a trade-off between model size and model accuracy. I think that I am missing something when configuring my spark-submit. I just set basic conf like executor cores, executor memory, driver instances, driver memory. But if I am not wrong, they only configure the memory allocated to the job and they don't correspond to the disk usage which is provided to this job. I finally add that my cluster is based on workers having very good memory/disk resources. So, I definitely think it is a matter of configuration.